# Java EE WebApplication on Tomcat6 Crashes

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, tomcat, crash, centos

I have a web application (J2EE+Tomcat6+MySQL+Struts2+Hibernate) running on a Linux Cent-OS. Sometimes(usually After about 3-4 days) it becomes inaccessible and I see a blank white page!
Both "/etc/init.d/httpd status" AND "/etc/init.d/tomcat status" say they are running fine.
I think my web-application crashes, because the Web-app can be up again when I restart the tomcat(restarting httpd solves nothing).
The project's logs shows nothing suspicious.
Please help me how can I trace the problem or find more about this crisis!
Is this a tomcat problem or what? reinstalling tomcat can help my case?

Comment: "project's logs shows nothing suspicious" I would double check the tomcat logs and any exception reports

Answer (score 0):

Narrowing down your problem is something no one can do for you, you need to shape up your general purpose debugging skills.

If your logs show nothing wrong, that only means your logging is wrong.
Probably also means you have a drowned exception somewhere.

I wouldn't reinstall anything, when bugs happen in 99.99% cases they are in your own code.
(when opposed to high-profile open-source systems)

Your best chance is also to pinpoint which servlet is returning you that blank page.
Is that page really blank? Check html source in your browser.

3-4 days bug period suggests a memory leak so I suggest using some java profiling tool on your app.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/

http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/11/11/troubleshooting-application-performance-with-visualvm/